# Service that is hosted either by IIS or Local Windows Service

Tags: wcf, asp.net-core

I'd like to develop Service that can be consumed either by REST Client or by tcp client. 
Which platform is currently suggested to accomplish such task. Is it still WCF or ASP.Net Core?

Comment: Could you share us more information about your scenario? What is the purpose for this service? For `.net core` and `wcf`, both could be consumed by rest client and tcp client.both could be hosted by IIS or windows service.

Comment: I'd like to know which technology is suggested. I'm afraid that WCF is a little bit outdated, isn't it?

Comment: WCF is suitable for Soap Service which needs security. For http request, you could try Asp.Net Core, if you prefer TCP or specify security requirement, you may consider WCF.